# Сравнить результаты двух подзапросов в SQLKata

Tags: c#, sql, postgresql

Я хочу сравнить результаты двух подзапросов в `WHERE`-секции в SQLKata

В SQL это выглядит следующим образом:

```
WHERE (SELECT count(id) FROM main.someTable) = (SELECT count(id) FROM main.anotherTable)
```

В SQLKata я могу сравнить результат подзапроса со скалярной величиной:

```
var mainSubquery = new Query("main.someTable")
            .SelectRaw("count(id)");

var anotherSubquery = new Query("main.anotherTable")
            .SelectRaw("count(id)");

query
    .WhereSub(mainSubquery, "=", 0)
```

Но я не могу сравнить результаты двух подзапросов друг с другом, например, таким способом:

```
query
    .WhereSub(mainSubquery, "=", anotherSubquery)
```

Как следует сравнивать? Возможно стоит выполнить оба подзапроса отдельно и потом сравнить результат их выполнения?

**UPD:** получил ответ от автора библиотеки

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74939077/how-to-compare-result-of-two-subqueries-in-where-clause-sqlkata/74948798#74948798

Comment: По-моему, решение очевидное: ```WHERE ( SELECT (SELECT count(id) FROM main.someTable) - (SELECT count(id) FROM main.anotherTable) ) = 0```. Если скаляризация не допускается, слить подзапросы во FROM.

Comment: @akina, тоже думал об этом решении, но также упираюсь в то, что не могу реализовать это в синтаксисе SQLKata.
Каким образом там вычитать результат второго подзапроса из результата первого подзапроса?

Comment: @akina, да, Дописал код в текст вопроса  - инициализацию mainSubquery и anotherSubquery

Comment: Ага, уже слазил, посмотрел документацию. Очередное го.. пардон, фреймворк. В общем, там есть WhereRaw, в который можно хоть слона затолкать. Его и используй.

Comment: @akina, проблема в том, что реальные подзапросы у меня существенно больше и чтобы не дублировать код мне нужно обойтись именно вызовом этих подзапросов, а не дублировать через WhereRaw. А вот как вызвать подзапрос в WhereRaw не очень понятно.

Но спасибо, что уделили время)

Comment: Получил ответ от автора библиотеки - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74939077/how-to-compare-result-of-two-subqueries-in-where-clause-sqlkata/74948798#74948798

Answer (score 0):

Можно посчитать разницу между двумя наборами (`(A-B) + (B-A)`), а потом убедиться, что она пустая

```
with A as (
  select col1, col2, col3 from table1
), B as (
  select col1, col2, col3 from table2
)  
select 
  not exists(
    (select * from B except all select * from A)
    union all 
    (select * from A except all select * from B)
  ) as "IsEqual?"
```

Например, запрос ниже возвращает `false`, пока все строки, помеченные `-- *` не будут удалены из обоих таблиц. После этого становится `true`

```
with A as (
  select 1 id, 'a1' str
  union all select 1 id, 'a1' str
  union all select 2 id, 'a2' str
  union all select 2 id, 'a2' str -- *
  union all select 3 id, 'a3' str 
  union all select 4 id, 'a4' str -- *
  union all select 4 id, 'a4' str -- *
  union all select 5 id, 'a5' str -- *
), B as (
  select 1 id, 'a1' str
  union all select 1 id, 'a1' str
  union all select 2 id, 'a2' str
  union all select 3 id, 'a3' str -- *
  union all select 3 id, 'a3' str
  union all select 6 id, 'a6' str -- *
)  
select 
  not exists(
    select * from B
    except all select * from A
    union all (select * from A
    except all select * from B)
  ) as "IsEqual?"
```

SQLKata умеет `except` / `union` https://sqlkata.com/docs/combine